# Loop T-Test for Comparison of Multiple Data Columns

Tags: python, pandas, python-unittest

I have a panda with 11 columns of data. I want to compare each column to every other column with a test (see below). How can I create a loop that automatically compares all columns without manually writing the code for each column-pair combination?

```
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind
data1 = [0.873, 2.817, 0.121, -0.945, -0.055, -1.436, 0.360, -1.478, -1.637, -1.869]
data2 = [1.142, -0.432, -0.938, -0.729, -0.846, -0.157, 0.500, 1.183, -1.075, -0.169]
stat, p = ttest_ind(data1, data2)
print('stat=%.3f, p=%.3f' % (stat, p))
if p > 0.05:
    print('Probably the same distribution')
else:
    print('Probably different distributions')
```

Is it possible to show the result in a matrix or graphically? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use a nested dict comprehension to calculate the `t-test` for every possible combination of columns, then initialise a new dataframe from the nested dict to create nicely formatted matrix representation:

```
dct = {x: {y: 's={:.2f}, p={:.2f}'.format(
          *ttest_ind(df[x], df[y])) for y in df} for x in df}
mat = pd.DataFrame(dct)


print(mat)
                 data1           data2
data1   s=0.00, p=1.00  s=0.33, p=0.75
data2  s=-0.33, p=0.75  s=0.00, p=1.00
```

---

If you need the matrix containing only `p-values`:

```
dct = {x: {y: ttest_ind(df[x], df[y]).pvalue for y in df} for x in df}
mat = pd.DataFrame(dct)

print(mat)
         data1    data2
data1  1.00000  0.74847
data2  0.74847  1.00000
```

To calculate the mean of all `p-values` use:

```
mat.to_numpy().mean()
0.8742349436807844
```

Note: `df` is the dataframe containing the columns `data1`, `data2` ...

Comment: Is there a way to calculate the average of all p values from the matrix?

Comment: yes, we can, but in that case we have to modify the dict comprehension..Are you also interested in `s` values from the result? If not we can remove the `s` values from the matrix representation then it will be much easier to calculate the average.

Comment: I am mostly interested in the p value, we can get rid of the s value. Thank you for your help!

Comment: thx! I tried your approach using _rel instead of _ind. Everything works perfectly well, except the mean, since I get Nan, is there a way to avoid the Nans when calculating the mean?

Comment: @CSBossmann Check `np.nanmean(mat.to_numpy())`

Answer (score 1):

If i got your question right you can do it like this:
(DATAS is just a sample DataFrame.
Result in the photo goes on,I just haven't shown all of it.)

```
DATAS=pd.DataFrame({"X":data1,"Y":data2,"Z":data3,"T":data4})

display(DATAS)



from scipy.stats import ttest_ind
for  a in DATAS.columns:
    for b in DATAS.columns:
        stat, p = ttest_ind(DATAS[a],DATAS[b])
        print('stat=%.3f, p=%.3f' % (stat, p))
        if p > 0.05:
            print('Probably the same distribution')
        else:
            print('Probably different distributions')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With sparse data in this example, the histograms will show you something but not everything.

```
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data1 = [0.873, 2.817, 0.121, -0.945, -0.055, -1.436, 0.360, -1.478, -1.637, -1.869]
data2 = [1.142, -0.432, -0.938, -0.729, -0.846, -0.157, 0.500, 1.183, -1.075, -0.169]
stat, p = ttest_ind(data1, data2)
print('stat=%.3f, p=%.3f' % (stat, p))
if p > 0.05:
    print('Probably the same distribution')
else:
    print('Probably different distributions')
plt.hist(data1, bins=5, color='c', edgecolor='k', alpha=0.5)
plt.hist(data2, bins=5, color='g', edgecolor='k', alpha=0.5)
```

you will get the plot like
[image: graph of the histograms]

For a real understanding of a Student T-test have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test